# How to make excel cells readonly using apache poi

Tags: apache-poi

In my case I need to protect single cell, to achieve this initially I used `HSSFCellStyle` and `setLocked(true)` and protect the sheet using `Sheet.protectSheet("password")`. This will protect non empty cell also so I am using `DataValidation` with single option, It is working as expected but it allows to delete the cell content without `validation.Below` is my sample code.Thanks in advance for your help.

```
 String errorBoxTitle = "Warning";
                    String errorBoxMessage = "Invalid Data";
                    String [] valueArr = {"cellValue"};

                    CellRangeAddressList cellValueAddress = new CellRangeAddressList(row.getRowNum(), row.getRowNum(), cell.getColumnIndex(), cell.getColumnIndex());

                    DVConstraint cellValueConstraint = DVConstraint.createExplicitListConstraint(valueArr);
                    DataValidation cellValueValidation = new HSSFDataValidation(cellValueAddress , cellValueConstraint );
                    cellValueValidation .setSuppressDropDownArrow(true);
                    cellValueValidation .createErrorBox(errorBoxTitle, errorBoxMessage);
                    cellValueValidation .setEmptyCellAllowed(false);
                    sheet.addValidationData(cellValueValidation );
```

Comment: It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve. A cell either can be locked or not locked. If it is locked, then it cannot be changed and also not be deleted. But it can be read. Maybe it cannot be selected because of the sheet protection settings. But that could be changed by setting sheet protection settings to not lock selecting locked cells. If a cell is not locked, then of course it also can be deleted.

Comment: @AxelRichter It is not really clear what you are trying to achieve >> I want to lock a single cell, for that i am using  HSSFCellStyle and setLocked(true) and protect the sheet using Sheet.protectSheet("password"), but **this is locking other empty cells also**. In my requirement I need to lock a single cell and all other cells(empty or non empty) should be editable.

Comment: It is the default in `Excel` that cells are locked when the sheet is protected. All not locked cells must have a cell style having `setLocked(false)` set.

Comment: Thanks @AxelRichter, Is there any other way to achieve my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A cell either can be locked or not locked. If it is locked, then it cannot be changed and also not be deleted. If a cell is not locked, then of course it also can be deleted. So since data validation needs to be used in not locked cells, data validation is not an option to protect against deleting.

If the goal is to have only some cells locked when the sheet is protected but most of the cells shall be not locked, then the only way is creating a cell style having `setLocked(false)` set and applying that cell style to all cells which shall be not locked. That is because it is the default in `Excel` that cells are locked when the sheet is protected.

If new cells in whole columns shall be not locked, then this `notLocked` cell style can be set as the default column style.

In the following example only the header cells `A1:C1` and all cells in columns greater than `C` are locked. The cells in `A2:C4` are not locked because the `notLocked` cell style is applied to that cells. Also the empty cells in columns `A:C` for rows greater than `4` are not locked because  the `notLocked` cell style is applied as the default column style for columns `A:C`.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLocked {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLocked.xlsx";
  Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLocked.xls";
  CellStyle notLocked = workbook.createCellStyle();
  notLocked.setLocked(false);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = null;
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
   cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellValue("Col " + (c+1));
  }

  for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue(r * (c+1));
    cell.setCellStyle(notLocked); 
   }
  }

  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, notLocked);
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, notLocked);
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(2, notLocked);
  sheet.protectSheet("");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is working fine now. Is there a way to set style for entire sheet or column range

Comment: @Velan: Not that I am aware of. `Excel` itself provides column info settings from first column to last column. But in `apache poi` there is only [Sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#setDefaultColumnStyle-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle-) for each single column.