# Protect the cell using apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I generated a column with 10 row, and each cell I put the value inside. I just want to protect the cell have a value (from A1 to A10).

Here is my code, But it not working?
How can I do it?

```java
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
        XSSFCellStyle lockStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        lockStyle.setLocked(true);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(i);
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("value " + i);
            cell.setCellStyle(lockStyle);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do this using `Excel` GUI? You need set the sheet protected using [Sheet.protectSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#protectSheet-java.lang.String-). After doing that all cells having `CellStyle.setLocked(true)` are locked. But locked true is the default. So you need using `CellStyle.setLocked(false)` for each cell which shall **not** be locked.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496992/how-to-make-excel-cells-readonly-using-apache-poi/59497751#59497751

Comment: So How can I set every cell unlock, then ```CellStyle.setLocked(true)``` for the cell I loop through

Comment: Please read my linked answer and the comments carefully.