# Is there a way to hide excel formula using Apache POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I want to populate column B value on basis of value selected in Drop down of column A. Working fine, with the help of VLOOKUP formula in all cells of column B. But now I want to hide the formula for column B cells, in order to avoid the formula alteration by user(even by mistake).

But formula should work as expected even after hiding it.

Is there any way to achieve it using Apache POI. Or Is there any other way to achieve auto population on basis of selection in drop down using Apache POI.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: I think that you probably want to 'lock' the cells - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496992/how-to-make-excel-cells-readonly-using-apache-poi

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Cell 'lock' already tried.
Column B is a field which contains VLOOKUP formula and a drop down in case if user want to enter some new value in Column A. If user selects new value in Column A then VLOOKUP will not populate anything in Column B, in that case user can select new value from Column B drop down. And if I lock the Column B cells then only formula will work but drop down won't work.
So. I'm looking for something which can hide (make alteration safe ) the formula but still let the user select value from drop down.

Comment: I don't want to make cell read only, but still want to hide the formula available for it.

Answer (score 1):

Hiding formulas is part of the cell style in Excel. So the simplest answer would be to use [CellStyle.setHidden(true)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setHidden-boolean-).

But that will only hide the formula but not prevent the formula alteration by user. This is what sheet protection is for. So you would need a combination of the both.

Following complete example shows that. Fomulas in `C2:C4` are hidden and protected.

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

public class CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLockedAndLockedHideFormulas {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLockedAndLockedHideFormulas.xlsx";
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); String filePath = "./CreateExcelDefaultColumnStyleNotLockedAndLockedHideFormulas.xls";
  
  CellStyle lockedHideFormulas = workbook.createCellStyle();
  lockedHideFormulas.setLocked(true);
  lockedHideFormulas.setHidden(true);
  CellStyle notLocked = workbook.createCellStyle();
  notLocked.setLocked(false);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = null;
  for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
   cell = row.createCell(c);
   cell.setCellValue("Col " + (c+1));
  }

  for (int r = 1; r < 4; r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   for (int c = 0; c < 2; c++) {
    cell = row.createCell(c);
    cell.setCellValue(r * (c+1));
    cell.setCellStyle(notLocked); 
   }
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellFormula("A" + (r+1) + "*B" + (r+1));
   cell.setCellStyle(lockedHideFormulas); 
  }

  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(0, notLocked);
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(1, notLocked);
  sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(2, notLocked);
  sheet.protectSheet("");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. Cell 'lock' already tried.
Column B is a field which contains VLOOKUP formula and a drop down in case if user want to enter some new value in Column A. If user selects new value in Column A then VLOOKUP will not populate anything in Column B, in that case user can select new value from Column B drop down. And if I lock the Column B cells then only formula will work but drop down won't work.
So. I'm looking for something which can hide (make alteration safe ) the formula but still let the user select value from drop down.

Comment: I don't want to make cell read only, but still want to hide the formula available for it.

Comment: @Rkmr039: Not possible as hiding formulas only takes effect if the sheet is protected. So you run into an Excel limitation here. Moreover your whole approach is sub-optimal. If the same cell contains a formula **and** a drop-down data validation, then the formula gets removed if the drop-down gets used and writes a literal value into the cell. A cell can only contain a formula **or** a literal value, not both.